# DocumentDb "where" clause with mathematical expression

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I would like to understand how to create query **where clauses** on DocumentDB with **mathematical comparator** inside.

For example, I used [this demonstrator](https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo) to understand how to make a "greater than" comparaison : expression `AND food.version > 0` seems to work very well.

Here is under what I tryed onto portal.azure.com documentdb query explorer and the results. I don't understand why I got an error in some cases(QUERY3), and (in option) how to get error details on portal.azure.com ?!

Tested:

```
>>> QUERY1 >>
SELECT d.id,
       d.name, 
       d.lastUpdateTime
FROM d 
>>> RESULT1 >>
[
  {
    "id": "558d6007b909e8dfb2286e7b",
    "name": "cSimpleSIMS_ici",
    "lastUpdateTime": 1435589982672
  },
  {
    "id": "558d6009b909e8df18296e7b",
    "name": "didier",
    "lastUpdateTime": 1435330811285
  },
  {
    "id": "558d600ab909e8df28296e7b",
    "name": "cDoubleSIMD_ici",
    "lastUpdateTime": 1435331176750
  },
  {
    "id": "558d600bb909e8df55296e7b",
    "name": "george",
    "lastUpdateTime": 1435330813519
  }
  (...)
]

>>> QUERY2 >>
SELECT d.id,
       d.name, 
       d.lastUpdateTime
FROM d 
WHERE (d.name='george')

>>> RESULT2 >>
[
  {
    "id": "558d600bb909e8df55296e7b",
    "name": "george",
    "lastUpdateTime": 1435330813519
  }
]

>>> QUERY3 >>
SELECT d.id,
       d.name, 
       d.lastUpdateTime
FROM d 
WHERE (d.lastUpdateTime > 14)
>>> RESULT3 IN ERROR!

>>> QUERY4 >>
SELECT d.id,
       d.name, 
       d.lastUpdateTime
FROM d 
WHERE (d.name='george' AND d.lastUpdateTime > 14)

>>> RESULT4 >>
[
  {
    "id": "558d600bb909e8df55296e7b",
    "name": "george",
    "lastUpdateTime": 1435330813519
  }
]


>>> QUERY5 >>
SELECT d.id,
       d.name, 
       d.lastUpdateTime
FROM d 
WHERE (d.name='george' AND d.lastUpdateTime > 1435330813519)

>>> RESULT5 >>
[]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here's the gist...**

Today, all JSON properties in DocumentDB get automatically indexed by a Hash index; which means queries with equality operators (e.g. `WHERE d.name= "george"`) are extremely fast.

On the other hand, range queries (e.g. `WHERE d.lastUpdateTime > 14`) require a range index to operate efficiently. Without a range index, the range query will require a scan across all documents (which we allow if the header, `x-ms-documentdb-query-enable-scan`, is passed in by the request).

The queries you issued that had both a equality and range filter (e.g. `WHERE d.name='george' AND d.lastUpdateTime > 14`) succeeded, because the equality filter greatly narrowed down the set of documents to scan through.

**TL;DR:** There are two things you can do here to get rid of the error:

1. Create a custom index policy to add a range index for numeric types. The documentation for indexing policies can be found [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-indexing-policies/).
2. Issue your query programmatically (not through the Azure Portal) to set the `x-ms-documentdb-query-enable-scan` header to allow scans on range queries.

**P.S. I will push to improve the Azure Portal for you.**

Now... there appear to be a few issues in the Azure Portal - which I will push to get fixed for you.

*Bug: Exception message is truncated*

Looks like the meaningful part of the exception message gets truncated out when using the Azure Portal - which is no bueno. What SHOULD have been displayed is:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: Message: {"Errors":["An invalid query has been specified with filters against path(s) that are not range-indexed. Consider adding allow scan header in the request."]}
```

*Missing Feature: Enabling scans in query explorer*

There ability to set the `x-ms-documentdb-query-enable-scan` header is currently not exposed in the Azure Portal's query explorer. We will add a checkbox or something for this.

Answer (score 1):

To add to aliuy's answer, we're working on a change that will improve the developer experience here - Default indexing policy for numbers will be changed from Hash to Range index, so you do not need the header or override indexing policy in order to perform range queries.